# Validación de número de teléfono / celular en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> Lo que necesito es una entrada donde un usuario de cualquier parte del mundo pueda poner su número de teléfono/celular y verificar si es válido, teniendo en cuenta la región del país y el código de área.
>   Se supone que se vea así:
>   "+ (Región del país) (Código de área) (Número de teléfono/celular)"
>
> Además, sería genial que, por ejemplo, el usuario escriba +54 automáticamente detecte que +54 es de Argentina.
>   O, estoy pensando en un input que despliegue cada país con su Región de país.
>   Como por ejemplo esto que encontré pero que no puedo replicar
>   [image: Sería algo así]

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]? y que intentaste hasta ahora? que tenes? la tabla de codigos de paises la tenes? como esperas validar el codigo de area? O sea, que queres hacer y que hiciste hasta ahora? porque asi como esta, parece muy amplia la pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Dices: *Lo que tengo hasta ahora hecho es esto* y cuelgas una imagen que no aporta nada. Como dice @gbianchi, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código, pero en formato texto, no en imagen. Saludos

Comment: Tengo un input vacio con el id telephone1, no tengo ni codigo de pais ni area.
Esperaba que cuente los caracteres en cada criterio
“+    (NNN)                         ( NNN)                     (NNNN-NNNN)”
  Pais hasta 3 char   cod area hasta 3 char   numero 9 char.
La pregunta es amplia porque estoy en 0, esperaba que me iluminen los maestros de StackOverflow

Comment: Que pongas el código @Joaquinc

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el problema o duda que tienes no es de código, es de datos.
La norma E.164 es un estándar de la ITU (Sector de Normalización de las Telecomunicaciones)  que define el formato de los números telefónicos

Un teléfono debe poder escribirse en un máximo de 15 números (3 para el prefijo del país), cuyo listado puedes ver en [este enlace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Alphabetical_listing_by_country_or_region).

La problemática viene al intentar validar los códigos regionales, dentro de cada país, pues deberías tener una base de datos, que dudo que exista de forma abierta y que posiblemente carezca de sentido hacerlo. Es lógico validar el código del país y el formato del número, no suele ser necesario saber de que provincia es un numero en concreto, si es que el número tiene código de provincia.

En [este repositorio](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/) de Github tienes la herramienta de validación de números que utiliza Android.